# Execute SSIS package on second server and write back to first server

Tags: ssis

I have two SQL 2016 servers - A and B. On Server A I have a SQL agent job with a step that executes an SSIS package that resides on server B. The package on server B adds a row to a table on server B and tries to write a row to a table on server A.

When the agent job on server A is run, the package succeeds in writing the row on server B (where the SSIS package is stored and is executing) but errors out when writing the row on server A (where the agent job is being run from).

Here's the error message I'm getting from the package:

> SSISTest:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.".

So the problem is when the package is trying to write the row to server A from server B.

How do I change the SSIS package on server B and provide credentials to write to server A? Or, have the agent job and package execute under the same domain login?

I've tried adding the SQL service accounts for both servers as sysadmins on each server. I've also created a credential and proxy account on server A using my domain login which is a sysadmin on both servers.

Comment: How is the package writing to table on server A? Via linked sever?

Answer (score 0):

It is a typical case of "Double Hop" authentication not working or not configured.
You have few options:
1. Simpler: always execute SSIS packages from local SQL Agent.
2. Long term: Configure Kerberos and enable double hop.

There is a documentation how to configure Kerberos:
[Understanding Kerberos](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/)
[Configure Kerberos for SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks - I beleive we've got Kerberos setup across the board, but I'll double check that as it sounds like it could be the answer.

Comment: Even if you have Kerberos, SPN may be not assigned to SQL Server. Error is typical for Kerberos.

Comment: Could you please explain what you think is the hop 1 and hop 2 in the current question?

Comment: Hop 1 is connection from Agent A to SSIS server, hop 2 is connection from SSIS server to any network resource, including db on server A.